# How to dynamically mock the Zfc User service

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit, zfcuser

**Situation:** I am testing a Zend controller action, where a user has to login or otherwise will get redirected:

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class GameController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
            $view = new ViewModel();
            $user = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity();
            $view->username = $user->getUsername();
            return $view;
        } else {
            $this->redirect()->toRoute("mymodule/overview");
        }
    }
}
```

My test case then looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyModuleTest\Controller;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;
use ZfcUser\Controller\Plugin\ZfcUserAuthentication;
use ZfcUser\Entity\User;

class GameControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(include __DIR__ . '/../../../../../config/application.config.php');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testIndexAction()
    {
        // Mock the authentication user
        $user = $this->createMock(User::class);
        $user->expects($this->any())->method('getId')->will($this->returnValue('1'));

        // Mock the authentication adapter
        $authentication = $this->createMock(ZfcUserAuthentication::class);
        $authentication->expects($this->any())->method('hasIdentity')->will($this->returnValue(true));
        $authentication->expects($this->any())->method('getIdentity')->will($this->returnValue($user));

        $this->dispatch('/mymodule/game');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(302);
        $this->assertModuleName('MyModule');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('mymodule/game');
        $this->assertControllerName('MyModule\Controller\Game');
        $this->assertControllerClass('GameController');
        $this->assertActionName('index');

        // TODO: Log in the user
        // How do I install the mocked Zfc authentication?

        $this->dispatch('/mymodule/game');
        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertModuleName('MyModule');
        $this->assertMatchedRouteName('mymodule/game');
        $this->assertControllerName('MyModule\Controller\Game');
        $this->assertControllerClass('GameController');
        $this->assertActionName('index');
    }
}
```

**Problem:** There are a few StackOverflow posts how to mock the ZfcUser authentication service, but how can I do this dynamically (Working code example)? First, I want to trigger the redirect (and check for the 302 HTTP code), then I want to login the user (mock it) and check it again (and receive a 200 HTTP code)

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the `ZfcUser` service in your tests. Testing the working of `ZfcUser` falls outside the scope of your application and is done in the tests for the `ZfcUser` module. For example here for 302 errors:

[ZfcUser/tests/ZfcUserTest/Controller/RedirectCallbackTest.php](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/c727fec00bfd3ba04af19848268f5d010619b30a/tests/ZfcUserTest/Controller/RedirectCallbackTest.php#L87)
[ZfcUser/src/ZfcUser/Controller/RedirectCallback.php](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/c727fec00bfd3ba04af19848268f5d010619b30a/src/ZfcUser/Controller/RedirectCallback.php#L48)
[ZfcUser/tests/ZfcUserTest/Controller/UserControllerTest.php](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/c727fec00bfd3ba04af19848268f5d010619b30a/tests/ZfcUserTest/Controller/UserControllerTest.php#L254)

### UPDATE:

So your `$this->zfcUserAuthentication()` method should return the mocked class that you prepared. This part of your code is not in the question, so I cannot give you more details on this.
Best would be to have the `ZfcUser` authentication service injected through constructor dependency injection (as a dependency in your class constructor).

Comment: I edited my answer and added the mocked user and authentication - as you said. But the problem is that I don't know how to install/inject the mocked object to Zend

Comment: You should mock the method `$this->zfcUserAuthentication()` to return the mock...